# Polymer: when is observer called

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

when is an observer in polymer 1.x called?

**a-component**

The a-component has a value property and an observer

```
properties: {
  aValue: {
    type: Number,
    observer: '_aValueChanged'
  }
}
```

**b-component**

The b-component has also a value property which can be used for two-way databinding.

```
properties: {
  bValue: {
    type: Number,
    notify: true
  }
}
```

It uses an a-component and two-way databinding to sync it's value.

```
<a-component id="a" a-value="{{bValue}}">
```

What happens if i change the vlaue of bValue

```
this.bValue = 1;
console.log(this.$.a.aValue);
```

Is it guaranteed that the observer of the a-compnent is executed before the console.log is executed?

Is it guaranteed that current value (1) is logged?

Thank you

Greets,
Meisenmann

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the observer is called before `console.log()` statement. And also `console.log(this.$.a.aValue)` will print "1". If the observer is not called, try using `this.set("bValue", 1);` instead of `this.bValue = 1;`